# Contour plot: density of sites with latitude and longitude locations

Tags: r, plot, contour, kernel-density

I have data of this format and want to make a contour plot. When I try to use the `density(z)` I get error message `"x must be numeric"`. I'm not sure how transform my data to make it the correct format to generate the contour. I just want it to be based on the density of points as the two columns represent my long/lat.

```
z <- c(
  c(8.83,8.89),
  c(8.89,8.94),
  c(8.84,8.9),
  c(8.79,8.852),
  c(8.79,8.88),
  c(8.8,8.82),
  c(8.75,8.78),
  c(8.8,8.8),
  c(8.74,8.81),
  c(8.89,8.99),
  c(8.97,8.97),
  c(9.04,9.08),
  c(9,9.01),
  c(8.99,8.99),
  c(8.93,8.97)
)
z <- matrix(z, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Like `x <- z[seq(1,length(z), 2)];y <- z[seq(2,length(z), 2)];contour(MASS::kde2d(x, y))`?

Comment: I tried that and got this error. Error in contour(MASS::kde2d(x, y)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'contour': Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'. @lukeA

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you posted your data wrongly. `dim(z)` is `NULL`, not `c(15,2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`density()` is used for **univariate** density estimation. Since you have two independent variables: `long` and `lat`, you should use `kde2d()` from R's default package `MASS`.

```
library(MASS)
fit <- kde2d(z[,1], z[,2])
contour(fit$x, fit$y, fit$z)
## show original data locations
points(z, pch = 19, col = 4)
```

[image: contour]

---

**Follow-up**

If you look at `?kde2d`:

```
Usage:

     kde2d(x, y, h, n = 25, lims = c(range(x), range(y)))
```

The default number of cells along each of `x` and `y` are `n = 25`, which gives you a 25 * 25 grid. Density estimation is done on this grids. Perhaps you are wondering why estimation is done on a regular grid. Because such grid is like pixels of a digital photo. Grid/raster like object is convenient for visualization. Actually, if you want computer to proceed 3D graph, you have to give it a raster like object.

In practice, you should choose `n` according to how many data you have. Note that a 25 * 25 grid has 625 cells, this is quite fair when you have 1000 data points. You can also try `n = 50`. Setting `n` is very similar to setting number of bins when you produce a histogram. As `n` increases, your resulting estimation is more jagged. Consider the histogram example if you are unclear:

```
x <- rnorm(200)
hist(x, breaks = 10)
hist(x, breaks = 20)
```

Precisely, density estimation is different to histogram; the former is a kernel smoother, while the latter is a primitive bin smoother. But the choice of `n` (refinement) does has equal effect.

Comment: Would this work if my data has an uneven proportion of long and lat values and not even scales like this example?

Comment: I have about 1000 lat/long points randomly throughout a country and want to make my contour based on the "density" or location of those

Comment: When I tried what you had it seemed to only give me a 25x25 matrix with a z value, not for all my points